# Is it possible to animate a strikethrough? CSS / JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, keyframe

I am trying to get the text decoration to appear from left to right, as if it is being crossed out with a pen.

Is there a way to do this without making changes to the text behind it?

Thanks in advance!

```js
document.querySelector('h1').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
e.target.classList.toggle('strikethrough')
})
```

```css
.strikethrough {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    text-decoration-style: wavy;
    text-decoration-thickness: 15%;
    animation: strike 3s linear;
}


@keyframes strike {
    0% {width: 0;}
    100% {width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<h1>CROSS ME OUT</h1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to accept using a straight line as the strike through (instead of depending on the font's own strikethrough styles), then it is just a matter of overlaying a div on top of the `<h1>` element and offsetting it 100% to the side using `transform: translateX(-100%)`. We give it a top border whose width is font-size dependent (i.e. use `em` units), and a color whose value is dependent on the current font color (i.e. use `currentColor`).

You can use CSS transitions set the duration and easing function of the entry of this line. When the `.strikethrough` class is added, the offset is simply set to `transform: translateX(0)`.

A caveat is that this trick only works for non-breaking lines. If your h1 element will render across multiple lines, then it wouldn’t work.

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
document.querySelector('h1').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
e.target.classList.toggle('strikethrough')
});
```

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 0.05em);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-top: 0.1em solid currentColor;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform .25s ease-in-out;
}

h1.strikethrough::after {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<h1>CROSS ME OUT</h1>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks, clear explanation too.